# complex sql query to update main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, join

i have 3 tables 
1)main_table
2)Flag_table
3)emp_flagdetails

main_table structure

```
emp_no   hod_no  emp_name              flgType
E51397  E44417  Asha V  
E42342  E44417  Shaikh Faiz Ahmed   
E06636  E44417  Balu  K U
```

in the above table i kept flgtype column blank to update later

now i have Flag_table structure as follow

```
FlagId  FlagCategory    FlagType
1         BM            BRML12B
2         BM            BRMM12B
3         BM            BRMRMB
4         BM            BRMCMB
5         BM            BRMZM
6         VH            BRML12V
7         VH            BRMM12V
8         VH            BRMRMV
9         VH            BRMCMV
```

emp_flagdetails structure is a follow

```
ecode   flag
E44417  BRML12B
E42342  BRMRMB
E06636  BRMZM
E51397   BRML12B
```

this is my tables structure,now my query is i want to update flgtype coloumn of main_table with flagcategory column of Flag_table ..in such way that if empno from main_table is present in emp_flagdetails table then we will check the flag column of emp_flagdetails  for that matching employee and then we get this flag column value  and  we will find this value in flag_table if it is present in the  flag_table  ,we will update main_table flgtype column with flagcategory column value....so the output will be as follow

```
emp_no   hod_no  emp_name              flgType
E51397  E44417  Asha V                 BM
E42342  E44417  Shaikh Faiz Ahmed      BM
E06636  E44417  Balu  K U              BM
```

please help me to write the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdb50/1)**

```
UPDATE m
SET m.flgType = f.FlagCategory
FROM main_table m
 JOIN emp_flagdetails fd
  ON fd.ecode = m.emp_no   
 JOIN flag_table f
  ON f.FlagType = fd.flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update main_table m, (select a.emp_no, b.flagcategory from emp_flagdetails a, flag_table b 
where a.flag = b.flagtype) s set m.flgtype = s.flagcategory where m.emp_no = s.emp_no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update main_table
set flagtype= (select a.flagcategory 
    from (    select m.empno, f.flagcategory
                 from main_table m,emp_flagdetails e , flag_table f  
                 where m.empno=e.ecode
                  and e.eflag=f.flagtype) a
    where  main_table.empno=a.empno) ;
```